# Firefox doesn't like margin auto with flex box model

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the header > section. It works fine with chrome and opera but firefox push to the left side. I created a class called `.body` with `width: 960px` and `margin: 0 auto`. It doesn't recognize `margin: 0 auto` on firefox (i am using firefox 18).

I have tried setting the `display` value to `inline-block` for `.body` class. It does centers it but it pushes the `nav` to bottom (for all browsers).

This is what i am trying to do

**HTML**

```
<header id="header">
<section class="body box">
  <section class="flex1">
    <a>MyWebsiteName</a>
  </section>
  <nav class="nav-list flex1">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -o-box;
  display: box;
 -webkit-flex-direction: row;
 -mox-flex-direction: row;
 flex-direction: row;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 -moz-box-align: center;
 -o-box-align: center;
 box-align: center;
}

.flex1 {
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 -moz-box-flex: 1;
 -o-box-flex: 1;
 box-flex: 1;
}

.body {
  clear: both;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #0C2C52;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .2em .1em rgb(78, 76, 76);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .2em .1em rgb(78, 76, 76);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .2em .1em rgb(78, 76, 76);
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 padding: 1em 0;
}

header > section {
  height: inherit;
}

#header section.flex1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-list {}

.nav-list > ul {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use only `<section class="body">`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the bit which alter your `margin: 0 auto;`:

```
.box {
  display: -moz-box;
}
```

It works fine if you leave only `<section class="body">`. [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/y87Pq/)

Comment: leaving that out brings it to the middle but it pushes the `ul` list down.

Comment: where do you want your `ul` to appear?

Comment: i am trying to horizontally align them

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not perfect but fairly convenient.

Personally, I am frustrated by the browser development teams (Microsoft, Mozilla, etc) for not playing well together in planning of HTML interfaces for their applications.  W3C simply isn't enforceable upon these companies yet: a major drawback for us, now approaching 2014 and still having these ridiculous grunt-level problems.  Being a decade in the biz, I'm a bit upset.  Please see answer below... (set width accordingly)

**Answer**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .box_wrap{margin:0 auto;width:50%;}
</style>

<div class="box_wrap">
    <div class="your_flex_box"> ... </div>
</div>
```